# How to put an imageview exactly on the top of the screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I'm trying to get my app bar to not have margin around it.

This is my app design:

[image: app design]

This is what I am trying to achieve in android studio, just the top white bar:

[image: what I am trying to achieve]

I have tried multiple methods but android studio seems to put that disgusting padding or whatever around my image view, it can't exactly fit it on the screen.

Comment: What is the parent layout of the ImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could understand from your question you want the top bar to look flush with the screen with no margin or padding.

You could try this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:elevation="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This would be the result

[image]

And in in your `style.xml` replace the base `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` theme with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: @SeriaAti glad I could help